# WinForms C# DataGridView force refresh

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, refresh

Baby steps rolling...  I have a form with a data grid bound to a table.  I have some textboxes on the form bound to the table[columns], so as I scroll the grid, the textboxes show corresponding data.

I go to an "Edit Mode" of the textboxes and change the content and hit a save button.  The grid doesn't refresh the changed context until I physically click in the cell which forces a call to the tables OnChanging and OnChanged events...

How can I FORCE whatever event to "flush" the table at the end of my edit and have it refreshed in the datagridview.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried calling the dataGridView's Invalidate method?

```
this.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
```

Comment: My bad.  The form level's "Click" event of the button was never being fired directly since I had used a custom class that had a default method behavior.  After adjusting that as needed, it works perfectly...  However, I did InvalidateROW for the one record in question.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a BindingSource?  If so, call its [EndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.endedit.aspx?ppud=4) method on the TextBox's Leave event.

Comment: No impact.  Both the grid (obviously), and the textboxes are bound to the DataTable instance, but appears I cant' force throw the Tables "OnChanging" / "OnChanged" event which is what happens when I re-click in the grid manually after saving an edit.